# Heterogeneity testing in logistic regression models

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, heterogeneity

We ran 5 separate **logistic regression models** testing a set of independent variables on 5 different country-specific datasets. Our goal was to assess the relative contributions of known risk factors of preterm birth to individual preterm birth risk. Risk factors include: age, education, smoking habits, etc.

We just received comments from reviewers and one of them is asking us to "**assess heterogeneity**" in our models. For example, is the variation in the association with smoking more than would be expected by the play of chance?

Could anyone explain **how to do this (in simple terms)?** We have been **using SPSS** for all our analyses so far and it would be great to hear how to do this with this software.

Comment: For a binomial response (ie, in logistic regression), the variance of the response is a function of the mean of the response. That is, essentially all LR models necessarily have heterogeneity.

Comment: I suspect the referee wants you to compare the five models using something like a meta-analysis framework. No idea how to do this in SPSS I am afraid.